# UITextField Delegate Return on mulitple text fields

Tags: uitextfielddelegate

Newbie here,

I have 4 textfields on my single-view app example (address, city, state and zip). I'm trying to use delegation from each to dismiss the keyboard when the user taps out of each. I can't have two identically named methods.

Here's the method to dismiss the address textfield:

-(BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)address

{

```
if (address == self.address)  

   {
      [address resignFirstResponder];
   }

return YES;
```

}

So, my return key can dismiss the keyboard only if the user is in the address textfield, but I can't figure out how to use delegation for the other textfields.  The delegate protocol documentation didn't have any specifics on this.

thanks,

J.

Answer (score 1):

And that's the use of the parameter passed in the textFieldShouldReturn delegate method.

If you have multiple text fields, the same delegate method will be called and the text field sender object is passed as the parameter.

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if (textField == self.addressField)  
    {
        //Do what you need to do if address field should return
    }
    else if (textField == self.cityField)  
    {
        //Do what you need to do if city field should return
    }

    return YES;
}
```

But if what you want is just to resign the text field and since the text field is passed as the sender, you can just resign the passed text field:

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```